# Minimarkdown formatting in SO comments

Tags: support, comments, markdown-rendering

According to the help page on formatting text in comments on this site, the backtick should format text as code.

```
like this
```

But that does not work. My comments will display on one line.

I have seen formatting in comments (or did I dream it). How is this done?

Comment: Backticks add inline code formatting, like this: `x = 2 + 2`. There are no code blocks (or even line breaks) in comments.

Comment: The code in your question is formatted using 4 spaces, not ``backticks, which makes it a bit unclear whether you're actually trying to use backticks to format code in comments (which `does work`).

Comment: Right.In the question and answer blocks the markdown work. I'm asking about the minimarkdown in the comment blocks. But I see here that it is the multiline I'm looking for. ``But the code font and bg work otherwise `` I had the wrong expectation. My apology.

Comment: This comment is typed in  
`` three lines enclosed in double backticks 
The first line is above 
And this is the third line`` I entered the newlines by pressing Shift+Enter. Enclosing each line in double backticks has the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mini-markdown code formatting in a comment field is not the same as the markdown code formatting in the question and answer fields. Thanks to Dukeling and duplode in the comment section.

In a question field, the code formatting will follow the indenting of the quoted text and span multiple lines.

```
In this way 
  you can display 
  a block of code.
```

In the comment field, the code formatting will put the quoted text into a code font. `In this way you can highlight the 'code' as code` but it will ignore newlines.