# I'd like to post a reply to this site, but part of the reply is in Delphi code. How do I do that?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I want to respond to a user on Stack Overflow with some comments and some Delphi code.

However, I cannot understand how to post the code section. The instructions do not make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: This question is a better fit for [meta] than it is for Stack Overflow! In the future, when you want to ask a question about how to use the site, make sure to ask it there instead of here on the main site, where it's off topic. In the meantime, [the help center page on post formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) should help you out.

Comment: Do you want to post code in a comment? If so, use `\``". That's a backtick which will format your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimarkdown formatting in SO comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368933/minimarkdown-formatting-in-so-comments)

Answer (score 8):

First of all, let me start by saying that Stack Overflow is not a forum. Its Q&A format is not designed for discussions. Or as the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) puts it:

> Ask questions, get answers, no distractions

If you can structure your reply as an answer (i.e., it **must** *attempt to answer* the original question and not just reply to a single user), then you may [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). See [this Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for information on how you can format the code in your answer.

Otherwise, you can post a comment. In which case, you're limited by the 600-character limit of a comment and you can't have formatted multiline code. You can, however, write single-line code wrapped in backticks. For more info, see the "Comment Formatting" section in the Help Center article mentioned above.

Alternatively, you could post the code to a third-party website (e.g., a GitHub gist, [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/faq#1), etc.) and include a link to it in your comment.